# Having issues using webshot on aws lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I tried to use webshot with aws lambda but got an error:

```js
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'graceful-fs'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node-webshot-master/lib/webshot.js:2:10)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:570:32)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)"
  ]
}
```

Here is my code:

```js
var webshot = require('./node-webshot-master/lib/webshot.js');

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {



  webshot('google.com', 'google.png', function() {

  });

};
```

I also included the screenshot of my code. Can anyone help me find out why I am having this error?

[link to code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KewLz.png)